# Container Optimized OS Graceful Shutdown of Celery

Tags: docker, celery, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-os

Running COS on GCE

Any ideas on how to get COS to do a graceful docker shutdown?

My innermost process is celery, which says he wants a SIGTERM to stop gracefully

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker

My entrypoint is something like

```
exec celery -A some_app worker -c some_concurrency
```

On COS I am running my docker a service, something like

```
write_files:
- path: /etc/systemd/system/servicename.service
  permissions: 0644
  owner: root
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Some service

    [Service]
    Environment="HOME=/home/some_home"
    RestartSec=10
    Restart=always
    ExecStartPre=/usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -u 2000 --name=somename --restart always some_image param_1 param_2
    ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/docker stop servicename
    KillMode=processes
    KillSignal=SIGTERM
```

But ultimately when my COS instance it shut down, it just yanks the plug.

Do I need to add a shutdown script to do a docker stop? Do I need to do something more advanced?

Comment: Have you managed to get this working? I am having the same problem and a shutdown-script doesn't even help.

Answer (score 1):

What is the expected exit status of your container process when when it receives `SIGTERM`?
Running `systemctl stop <service>` then `systemctl status -l <service>` should show the exit code of the main process. Example:

`Main PID: 21799 (code=exited, status=143)`

One possibility is that the process does receive `SIGTERM` and shuts down gracefully, but returns non-zero exit code.
This would make the systemd believe that it didn't shutdown correctly. If that is the case, adding

`SuccessExitStatus=143`

to your systemd service should help. (Replace `143` with the actual exit code of your main process.)